# Putting a working union query into a subquery causes JOIN syntax error

Tags: ms-access

When I try to run the following query in Access 2016, I get a "Syntax error in JOIN operation" message.

Tables in use:

VISIB_BOMS is basically a self referencing hierarchy of part numbers in a Bill of Materials. (Similar to the classic example of an employee table where the employee can manager other employees.)

ztbl_IFSParts is just 1 column table of part numbers that I want to get the sub-component part numbers for.

The end goal is to have a single column table of all component parts from the parts from ztbl_IFSParts. I'll then use this list to get further info from JOINs to other tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    /* CODE BETWEEN HERE WORKS */
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT aa0.PartNo AS PartNo
        FROM ztbl_IFSParts AS aa0
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT b0.COMPPARTNO AS PartNo
        FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT aa0.PartNo AS PartNo
            FROM ztbl_IFSParts AS aa0
        ) AS ab0
        LEFT JOIN VISIB_BOMS AS b0
        ON ab0.PartNo = b0.ASSYPARTNO
    )
    /* CODE BETWEEN HERE WORKS */   
)
```

If I run the code between the comments on its own it works fine, only when I try to do any SELECT operations on it, it throws an error.

Hope it's enough info to run with.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the brackets around the two queries either side of the UNION ALL solved this.